# Is there a way to change keys in leveldb?

Tags: leveldb

Is there some how to change only the value of the keys in a leveldb database?

I already have a database with 18 milion rows, and I would like to change keys to add a prefix.

I am using leveldb with node.js. But any solution must fit.

I have already tried to rebuilt this database, but it costs too much time.

Comment: This doesn't look possible (even using native API). Still, what is the  size of each record? 18 Millions doesn't look too much.

Comment: I propose to ask your question at the [leveldb mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/leveldb)

Comment: @Lol4t0: The problem is the base is in production. The files have about 9GB.

Comment: Just rebuild from snapshot of production DB to another one adding new data to both. Then swap them in a moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way LevelDB works, every "Put" is a write that creates new state.
If you do a "Put" that overwrites an existing value, you'll have two
copies until compaction eliminates the older value.

Practically, this means that rebuilding will be the only option.

To make it faster you can try:

- Scan the existing database, and rebuild by doing a linear scan
  through the keyspace.  Your new data will be inserted in sorted
  order, which may help speed things up.
- Insert in batches.  Many variants of LevelDB will slow down writes to
  accommodate compaction.  In the stock LevelDB, your writer will sleep
  1ms whenever it needs to sleep and this is independent of the number of writes in the batch.
- Increase the write buffer size.  I've found 16MB-32MB to be a good "sweet spot".
- Consider using [HyperLevelDB](http://hyperdex.org/performance/leveldb/).  We were running into some
  performance issues with LevelDB with writes, and made some changes
  that improve performance.  You'll see your insertion speed go up,
  which could help you rebuild faster -- sometimes significantly
  faster.